# Copy sheets between two Workbooks that have Formulas in it

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am trying to copy sheets between to two workbooks. This is the code that  i have. xlWorkbook contains the data and i want to add sheets from xlDesTemplatebook that contains all my formulas.The code works and copies all the sheets but cells with formulas are appearing as #REF & if i select the cell having formulas and then hit enter it works.But my problem is that i am using the xlworkbooklater in my program for which i need the calculated data not the #REF in those cells. How can i fix this ?

```
 xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text)
 XlDesTemplateBook=xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\Formulas.xlsx")
 Dim oSheetsList() As Object = {"IB6", "IB7", "IOB6", "IOB7", "LI", "LO", "VB"}
 XlDesTemplateBook.Sheets(oSheetsList).Copy(After:=xlWorkBook.Worksheets("PLC EXPORT-VB"))
```

Screenshot Showing my issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got round this by doing the following:

1) make a copy of the sheet you want to send

2) select all or just the cells with formulae

3) do edit/ replace and replace = with xyxyxy or something that never appears

4) move the sheet over to the other workbook

5) select all and replace xyxyxy with =

Always works fine for me...

Comment: I have lot of Formulas like this "=IF(ISBLANK('LOCAL IO '!C2),"SPARE",'LOCAL IO '!C2)" in each cell. I have 6 sheets and upto 400 cells in each sheet. So i cant find and replace for every single formula

Comment: I have to move some of my "special" sheets (which grade 40 groups with 240 students and 6 faculty with 40 categories per student so several thousand cells and it works for me... Once you replace the "=" then it is just text and then the links don break unlike the ref error you get - and it was to get round exactly that problem that I came up with that method... BTW you can select all the sheets and all cells together...

Comment: Have you considered having a sheet in the template file so you paste the data then save-as so moving the data instead of the formulae...

Comment: I tried your tip and it works But i didn't figured it out yet how to do that in VB.net. I will wait for some more time if any other way to do this vb.net. Or else i will mark yours an answer

Comment: Well, you could have the template file already prepared so your vba just copies over the sheets then do the edit/replace of xyxyxy to "=" which would save a bit of grief coding...